# Django groups and special permissions

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-authentication, django-users

Can any one guide me in this: is there any way to create django groups where there should be a group admin who can control the activity of the group and can add members and the members can share any kind of photos within the group and the other members outside the group can't view/access the photos/media?

Comment: What did you try? Did you read the documentation?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a minute to read [ask] in order to know what kind of questions will have a bigger chance of being answered. Users will be happy to help you with specific problems, not broad questions like this one.

Comment: @patrick i didnt try / read the documentation i just want to know is it possible if so how if you can share me links regarding the documentation/or anyother material regarding this question it will be. Helpfull for me thanks in advance

Comment: Then I suggest you make yourself familiar with https://www.djangoproject.com/ and if you encounter specific problems: show the Code that causes it and ask specific questions.